# In Scheme, can if be expressed as a combination of boolean operators?

Tags: scheme, boolean-logic, syntactic-sugar

It is easy to express `and`, `or`, and `not` in terms of `if` (with an assist from a local binding for `or`). I'd like to know if the reverse is true. My naïve first attempt:

```
(if test conseq altern) => (or (and test conseq) altern)
```

However, if `test` is non-`#f` and `conseq` is `#f`, the translation evaluates to `altern`, which is incorrect.

Is there a translation that evaluates to the correct value while maintaining the short-circuit nature of `if`?

Comment: Maybe (or (and test (or conseq #t)) altern) ?

Comment: Ah, but then `(if #t #f #t)` would evaluate to `#t`. These are the sorts of tricks I'm looking at to solve it, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you have a good explanation why `if` is doing a little more than `and` and `or`.  But if you could cheat and add a `lambda` to delay the actual result:

```
(define-syntax-rule (if c t e) ((or (and c (lambda () t)) (lambda () e))))
```

Comment: Nice; I like the idea of adding a touch of laziness. Any thoughts on how it might be possible without cheating?

Comment: laziness is not necessary. the important thing is to wrap it inside anything that makes it evaluate to true, and then extract it

Comment: You *need* that laziness -- in other words, you need the wrap to contain a *computation* rather than a *value*.  Otherwise you don't get the short-circuiting property that makes `(if #f (print-stuff) 1)` not print stuff.

Comment: Barzlay: the short-circuiting is done by the `and` and `or` already

Comment: @user102008 But wouldn't then both `conseq` and `altern` expressions get evaluated, which Scheme's built-in `f` avoids?

Comment: @bellpeace: this is a syntax rule, not a function

Answer (score 2):

Try `(or (and test conseq) (and (not test) altern))` as the general pattern. By negating `test` in the second `and`, it ensures that the outer disjunction will be either `conseq` ∨ `#f` if `test` is true, or `#f` ∨ `altern` if `test` is false.

Comment: The downside is that this can evaluate "test" twice

Comment: Nice; locally binding `test` and using this pattern looks like it'd work. I wonder if it's possible without the binding, though?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as Eli Barzilay's answer, except instead of wrapping it in a lambda, I wrap it in a 1-element list

```
(if test conseq altern) => (car (or (and test (list conseq)) (list altern)))
```

By the way, Python prior to 2.5 had this exact problem. There was no nice way to write a conditional expression (i.e. `test ? conseq : altern` in C, which is what `if` in Scheme is) in Python. The simplest attempt was

```
test and conseq or altern
```

which worked in most cases, but failed when `conseq` is considered false in Python (i.e. False, 0, empty list, empty string, etc.). Which is the exact problem you discovered above. The fix was to wrap it in a list (non-empty lists are always true) and extract it again:

```
(test and [conseq] or [altern])[0]
```

which looks ugly. Which is why they added the syntax `conseq if test else altern` in Python 2.5.